# Spring @Autowired throwing Null pointer exception when overriding retrieveUser() method of Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring application which implemented spring security.I was trying to overide method UserDetails retrieveUser(String username,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken pWord){} by extending my LoginController with AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider

In this Class I used @Autowired annotation like

```
@Autowired
private UserManager userManager;
```

Unfortunately userManager is null  inside retrieveUser method
Following is My code:
LoginController.java

```
package com.springmaster.controller;
...
....
@Controller
public class LoginController extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {    
    @Autowired
    private UserManager userManager;

    /**
     * @return the userManager
     */
    public UserManager getUserManager() {
        return userManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param userManager the userManager to set
     */
    public void setUserManager(UserManager userManager) {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(
            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        System.out.println("----------"+this.userManager); //getting not  null here
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");

        return model;
    }

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails arg0,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken arg1)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken pWord)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String password = (String) pWord.getCredentials();
        UserManager userManager = new UserManagerImpl();


        System.out.println("----------"+this.userManager);  //getting null here
        List <UserEntity> userEntities= userManager.getAllUsers(username);

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_Admin"));
        return new User(username, password, true, // enabled
                true, // account not expired
                true, // credentials not expired
                true, // account not locked
                authorities);
    }


}
```

Spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmaster.*" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"></bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"></bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userProfile" class="com.springmaster.entity.UserProfileEntity"></bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_Admin" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/admin"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>
    <!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
    <beans:bean id="CustomAuthenticationProvider" class="com.springmaster.controller.LoginController">
    </beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="CustomAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <!--  -->
<!-- needed for ContextLoaderListener -->
    <!-- <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/springmaster/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
 -->
    <!-- Bootstraps the root web application context before servlet initialization -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>  


    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Some research gave a brief idea about it like

```
web.xml is creating two Spring application contexts. Let's call them Security (after security-context.xml) and Servlet (after servlet-context.xml). Security is created by the ContextLoaderListener listener, and Servlet is created by the DispatcherServlet servlet. Security is the parent of Servlet. That means that the beans in Security are only visible to other beans in Security, and the beans in Servlet can see both the beans in Security and in Servlet.
```

As a beginner can any one tell me what all configuration I should do in configuration files to overcome this barrier

Any Help will be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you have to registered UserManager in context. Add UserManager as bean in your Spring-Security.xml

Comment: @dhamibirendra :If you see the above LoginController , userManager object is getting inside login() method but not in overriding retrieveUser() methos.Actually I am investigating exact reason for this and change configuration so that userManager object will be available in both method.Do you have any idea?

Comment: you have the same controller registered in two contexts.  Don't have a controller be an auth provider AND a controller, it's weird.  split your class into two classes

Comment: chris-damour:I can split that.But how that will resolve my abouve problem.Asking for a solution for above problem

Comment: I did it by changing web.xml                         <context-param>
 
 
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
   /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
  </param-value>
 </context-param>